# where is the triangle inequality hidden in "positive semidefinite"-ness

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

[image]

For reference, this is a result used in the "Are These Distances Euclidean?" chapter of Matousek's *Thirty-three Miniatures*.

By "triangle inequality," he's referring to the fact that: if you want three points p,q,r to have some fixed distances between each other (can be a different distance for each pair), then a necessary condition for the existence of such points is that they must satisfy the triangle inequality.

(So I believe this theorem is giving something stronger than triangle inequality, that ends up being necessary and sufficient for this "points exist given distances" problem.)

I did some calculations, but haven't really gotten anywhere...I have:

- $g_{0i}, g_{i0} = 0$
- $g_{ii} = m_{0i} = \| p_0 - p_i \| $

and then some other calculations that seem way too in the weeds.

Comment: Have you checked the case $n=2$ (three points)?

Comment: I think what the author means is that the triangle inequality is less fundamental than the defining properties of inner product. Indeed, the triangle inequality follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the latter is a consequence of the defining properties of inner product.